# How to find a crontab entry that isn't listed in crontab -e

Tags: debian

I'm root user on my server and in the logs I found a running crontab that shouldn't be there.

In the log files I have:

```
Jun 22 09:00:01 lechnerio-srv CRON[18637]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nice -n 5 /usr/bin/php 
-q /var/www/froxlor/scripts/froxlor_master_cronjob.php --tasks 1> /dev/null)
```

from a previous froxlor installation. However, in the crontab from the user `root` there isn't any froxlor cronjob remaining. Is there any easy way to find the crontab entry other than checking all the users from `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: system crontabs are in `\etc\cron*`. `crontab -l` in root gives you jut the crontab of the root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check all crontab for all user

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```